# Does QtObject have a destroy() method?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

This code runs without error:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    QtObject {
        id: foo
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        foo.destroy()
    }
}
```

But the docs for QtObject don't say it has a destroy() method. So does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destroy()` method is for deleting [dynamically created objects in QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html). The `QtObject` in your example is statically created, and the above documentation says that you cannot call `destroy()` on such objects:

> This would result in an error, since objects can only be dynamically destroyed if they were dynamically created.

I am not sure why you do not get an error in your example, but this is definitely not something you should do.